# Using a laptop as a server

Tags: battery

I've got a windows 8.1 laptop (Dell). I need to configure it remotely over the next few weeks (I'll be out of the country).

I'd like to have it running 24 hours a day as a server, to do this. I'll use a remote access system like team viewer.

The problem is that it keeps shutting down and thus disconnecting me.

- Firstly, is it possible to have a remote session running in the background? That is, without having the laptop itself logged on, or running at the same time as the laptop is logged into a different account?
- Secondly, is it possible to set up some sort of macro so that, when it disconnects from the network, it can log-in again? That is re-join the domain.
- Finally, is there anything else that you have to do for this to work?

Comment: People used a potato as webservers, so don't worry. http://d116.com/spud/

Answer (score 1):

A laptop works great as a server **once you set the power options properly**.  You have built-in protection against power loss, assuming your battery works.

Press the Windows key + R, then type `powercfg.cpl`, then Enter.  You'll be brought to the Power Options.

Then select High Performance.

Then, select "Adjust when the system sleeps ..." or similar at the left and change each setting to Never (you never want the system to sleep - whether or not you want the display or hard drive off is your call but I'd set that to "Never" as well.)

Finally, go through Advanced options and change things like "PCI Link State Management" to "Maximum Performance." or something that makes sense for what you are trying to do.

> Secondly, is it possible to set up some sort of macro so that, when it disconnects from the network, it can log-in again? That is re-join the domain.

I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "re-join" the domain as systems can only be removed from a domain by going to `sysdm.cpl` or when your system administrator makes changes in Active Directory.  Loss of network connectivity doesn't cause this.

You probably mean having your remote access software become available again after a sudden reboot.  For this, whatever solution you select will need to be installed and run as a Windows service.  In this way, when you start the remote client, you can log in if you aren't logged in.

VNC can do this, but something tells me you are depending on the fact that services like Teamviewer act as an "intermediary" in order to work without you having to open router ports and deal with NAT.  Teamviewer allows installation as a service and it did not take much effort to find their PDF documenting the simple process.  You probably have to buy a valid license for Teamviewer to get a permanent password, which seems like its required. Other services like LogMeIn, etc. I imagine would be similar.

One thing to keep in mind is shut your laptop screen before you go.  No need to have the LCD backlight burning while you are gone.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just change the Power Management options in the Control Panel, so it doesn't shut down down the PC and drop from the network?

I don't really know what kind of remote session you want running in the background?

Answer (score 0):

When TeamViewer is installed it will automatically install itself as a service. Thus as you are logged in you will be able to lock and unlock your pc. Take notice here that you won't be able to log-in when you are logged of. (This just doesn't work like that).

In a normal situation you should not disconnect from your network on a windows machine. However if this happens in your situation I would need more information to debug this.

As for the shutdown behavior, make sure that in your Power Management all settings for shutdown/sleep/hibernat/whatsoever are disabled or set to your likings.

Good luck and have a great out of country experience (Read holiday when appropriate ;))